# What is the difference between Collections and "Stored Collections" in Java? and why "Stored"?

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between Collections and "Stored Collections" in Java? and why they are called "Stored"?

Comment: Where do you have seen both terms ? I don't understand the question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/createbindingscollections.html          --> second paragraph

Comment: First link on google for "Java stored collections": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/UsingStoredCollections.html

Comment: Section Stored Collections Versus Standard Java Collections

Comment: yes, already seen this. I am a newbie. need a less technical explanation

Comment: Stored Collections are not a standard JDK feature. This is some addition from Oracle based off of Berkeley DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored Collections are not a standard java concept. I assume you are referring to the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/UsingStoredCollections.html) concept. That link describes some of the differences, but the upshot is that the database is using (abusing - because it violates the contract) the `Collection` interface in order to provide storage in a database. Standard java Collections are in-memory only objects, and storage and retrieval are done with separate APIs.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard about "stored collections" in the default Java API. There are stored collections in certain database-related libraries, however. For example, the Java libraries for Oracle have so called "stored collections", which are basically nothing else than collections that can be persisted using an Oracle database.

Answer (score 2):

Collection in general describe an object which can handle a number of other objects. Stored collections is a term used to describe collections stored in a database (hence the term).